# Problemas instalando algunos módulos en Python

Tags: python, anaconda, instalacion

¡Buenos días!

Estoy tratando de instalar algunos paquetes en python. Uso Jupyter Notebook, de Anaconda.
Voy al terminal y pongo lo siguiente:

```
conda install Extractor
```

ó:

```
conda install util
```

Supongo que con otros paquetes pasará lo mismo, pero lo he probado con estos dos. El caso es que en ambos casos me salta el siguiente error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - util

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

¿Cuál es el problema? Con Extractors me pasa lo mismo. No entiendo qué pasa, dado que el error no dice que el paquete no exista (si pongo algo tipo "conda install cdvsdfvgjsdfgv" me salta una línea en rojo diciendo que eso, evidentemente, no existe).

Agradeceré una ayuda en esto.

¡Mucas muchas gracias!

Un saludo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error significa que el paquete no está disponible en los **canales** que tienes establecidos.

En el caso del paquete ***extractor***, buscándolo en el sitio web [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org), el único resultado con dicho nombre que aparece es este [paquete](https://anaconda.org/auto/extractor). Este paquete pertenece al canal ***auto*** y parece ser compatible sólo con **Linux**.

Prueba a instalarlo ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
conda install -c auto extractor
```

Si no puedes instalarlo con el comando anterior, como el paquete parece estar disponible en el repositorio [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/Extractor/), y parece ser independiente del sistema operativo, puedes intentar instalar el paquete de este repositorio a través de PIP, ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
pip install Extractor
```

Comment: ¡Funcionó! Mucas gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber ayudado.